# How to open a file in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to open a file in kivy. How do you open a file because my app includes opening txt files so my idea is when someone presses a button in my app a menu comes up and they select the file I then copy the file to the directory where my app stores the txt files. Is there alredy a module for this in kivy?

Answer (score 0):

This is my "storage.py" file in every kivy project: :)

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

def get(path, data={}):
    try:
        return JsonStore(path).get('data')["data"]
    except:
        print("no data found so we create", path, data)
        JsonStore(path).put("data", data=data)
        return data

def set(path, data):
    JsonStore(path).put("data", data=data)
```

Comment: No I mean like a button that would open a screen and a user would select a file

Comment: Oh ! Then you may want to use https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.0/components/file-manager/